# extract quarter from datetime column in presence of NaN in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I need to extract quarter from pandas datatime column as `Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4`. Example code is below:

```
dfm = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [None, '2018/02/03', '2019/09/30', '2017/05/12']})
dfm.Date = pd.to_datetime(dfm.Date, format='%Y/%m/%d')
dfm['Quarter'] = dfm.Date.dt.quarter
dfm['Quarter'] = dfm.Quarter.apply(lambda x: 'Q'+ str(x))
```

What I got is `Q1.0 Q2.0 Q3.0 Q4.0`.  The problem came from `dfm['Quarter'] = dfm.Date.dt.quarter`. In presence of `NaT`, what I got is float, rather than integer.

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dt.to_period` with `strftime` to get the correct format:

```
dfm['Quarter'] = dfm['Date'].dt.to_period('Q').dt.strftime('Q%q')

        Date Quarter
0        NaT     NaT
1 2018-02-03      Q1
2 2019-09-30      Q3
3 2017-05-12      Q2
```

---

Or with `str.extract`, but `NaT` get's converted to `NaN`:

```
dfm['Quarter'] = dfm['Date'].dt.to_period('Q').astype(str).str.extract('(Q\d)')

        Date Quarter
0        NaT     NaN
1 2018-02-03      Q1
2 2019-09-30      Q3
3 2017-05-12      Q2
```